# Stuck at Boot from CD/DVD:

Tags: software-installation, live-usb

Trying to install Ubuntu, but when I select the boot drive, it says Boot from CD/DVD:

Please help, because I really want to use this OS to speed up my pc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running with the limited info you're giving us here.

You need to create a bootable USB using [one of the official images](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). Then setup your motherboard to boot first from USB and just follow the installing procedure. Don't run from Live USB, explicitly say you want to install Ubuntu.

Comment: I am trying to install kubuntu from ubuntu(damn autocorrect) and i made it from startup disk creator. It just says Boot from CD when I already have it installed, burned properly, and I selected it. I mean, when I did boot it one time I selected check disk for defects, idk if that's the problem, or I am missing something in the process. I have tried: reburning the image; re-downloading the image to see if the one I had had an erroe. All except using another flash drive (now that I think about it, should I use my hard drive?) Thank you for your reply, by the way.

Comment: So, your goal is to install Kubuntu, starting from a Ubuntu install? Unless you have a strong reason to, you don't really need to go Kubuntu. What happens when you choose the option "Boot from CD / DVD"? Can you actually install the OS or not? You can always try to burn the image on a USB stick. 

I'm glad to help! I'm sure you'll pay it forward in the future. ;)

Comment: #1 I can't choose an option because it's on the post that I get it from. #2 I am trying to get the OS on a USB stick. Sorry if I came off a bit too mad there lol.

Comment: You need to give me a more thorough description. I really can't figure what your problem is. Sorry. :/

Comment: I figured it out. The usb wasn't formatted through, and I just had to unchecked quick format. Thanks for at least trying to help, I guess :/

Comment: Aha! All is well when it ends well. Hope you love your new system! :)